# Display all records with an id smaller than 100 fails due to 'comparison of Symbol with 100 failed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comparison

I have a user model and I need to display all users that have an id of smaller than 100. My code is

```
User.where(:id < 100)
```

The error message is "comparison of Symbol with 100 failed". How can I just get all users with ids smaller than 100? How will it be if I need ids between 100 and 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop into a SQL where clause for that:

```
User.where("id < 100")
```

But there's a gem that will let you do what you're trying to do: [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel). With that installed you could get the same result with:

```
User.where{id < 100}
```

For the range test:

```
User.where("id > 100 and id < 200")
```

or with squeel:

```
User.where{id > 100 and id < 200}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid SQL or an additional gem like suggested by @Mori you can do

```
User.where(:id => 1..100)
```